# PHP extensions loading in apache module, but not in CLI

Tags: php, apache, homebrew, command-line-interface

I've just performed a fresh install of php 5.5(.19) on Mac OSX 10.10.1 through Brew and symlinked `libphp5.so` from the Brew install to `/usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`.

Firing up a script through Apache with `phpinfo()` tells me that the loaded `php.ini` file is located at `/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini`.

I've added this to the bottom of the `php.ini`:

```
extension=memcache.so
extension=memcached.so
extension=imagick.so
extension=mongo.so
extension=mcrypt.so
```

I should mention that these modules are installed with Brew also. They load without issue when using PHP as an Apache module. However, when using php from the terminal, I receive the following output:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/memcache.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/memcache.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/memcache.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/memcache.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/memcached.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/memcached.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/memcached.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/memcached.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/imagick.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/imagick.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/imagick.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/imagick.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mongo.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mongo.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mongo.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mongo.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mcrypt.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mcrypt.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mcrypt.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mcrypt.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

When running:

`php --ini`

I receive the output:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/5.5
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-memcache.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-memcached.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini
```

So I can see, that the loaded configuration file is the same as the one used when running as an Apache module.

Running:

`php -v`

gives me:

```
PHP 5.5.19 (cli) (built: Nov 25 2014 11:47:10)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.6, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
```

So I know it's using the correct installation (Yosemite default PHP version is 5.5.14).

I can't seem to find out why the extensions load without issue when using Apache, but not when using CLI. How do I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I has the similar issue with `mcrypt` extension.

Solved it by removing `extension=mcrypt.so` from main `php.ini` because the extension was included in additional file, from `conf.d` path. I think you can solve your problem it in same mode. Just remove all rows that you are included in your `php.ini`.

Good luck!